# Storing increments of a recursive method in java

Tags: sorting, performance, recursion, java, quicksort

I am having a difficult time on a project I am currently doing. I need to find the efficiency of the quick sort method by placing counters in the recursive method for comparisons and assignments. How do I sum those counters up? Once the method ends, and is recalled, the counter is set back to 0. What can I do to improve my code? I tried to store each one in a linked list, but that did not work.

My code:

```
public class QuickSort {

    public static void quickSort(int[] array3){   
        System.out.println("\n" + "The efficiency of the quick sort is:");
        int comp = 0;
        int swap = 0;
        quickSort(array3, 0, array3.length - 1);
        System.out.println("\n");
        for (int index = 0; index < array3.length; index++){
            System.out.print(array3[index] + " | ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n" + "A(n)= " + swap);
        System.out.println("C(n)= " + comp);
        System.out.println("T(n)= " + (swap + comp));
    }

    public static void quickSort(int[] array3, int first, int last){
        if(last > first){
            int pivotIndex = partition(array3, first, last);
            quickSort(array3, first, pivotIndex - 1);
            quickSort(array3, pivotIndex + 1, last); 
        }
    }

    public static int partition(int[] array3, int first, int last){

        int pivot = array3[first];
        int low = first + 1;
        int high = last;
        int comp = 0;
        int swap = 0;
        while (high > low){
            while (low <= high && array3[low] <= pivot){
                low++;
                comp++;
            }
            while (low <= high && array3[high] > pivot){
                high--;
                comp++;
            }
            if (high > low){
                int temp = array3[high];
                array3[high] = array3[low];
                array3[low] = temp;
                swap = swap + 3;
                comp++;
            }
        }
        while (high > first && array3[high] >= pivot){
            high--;
            comp++;
        }
        if (pivot > array3[high]){
            array3[first] = array3[high];
            array3[high] = pivot;
            swap = swap +2;
            comp++; 

            System.out.println("A(n) = " + swap);
            System.out.println("C(n) = " + comp);
            return high;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("C(n) = " + comp);
            return first;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: We need two things: (1) a better description of what you're trying to do - "placing counters in the recursive method for comparisons and assignments" doesn't tell us how that will measure efficiency, and (2) a decent description of "that did not work" for the method you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a property defined in your class to keep track of the counter.

Just move comp and swap to properties in your class and don't re-define them in quickSort.

```
public class QuickSort {

    static int comp = 0;
    static int swap = 0;

    public static void quickSort(int[] array3){            
        System.out.println("\n" + "The efficiency of the quick sort is:");
        comp = 0;
        swap = 0;
        quickSort(array3, 0, array3.length - 1);
        System.out.println("\n");
        for (int index = 0; index < array3.length; index++){
            System.out.print(array3[index] + " | ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n" + "A(n)= " + swap);
        System.out.println("C(n)= " + comp);
        System.out.println("T(n)= " + (swap + comp));
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: `comp` and `swap` should be static, or this code won't compile.

Comment: @Eran - thanks I missed it was a static function. Updated. user3285126, if you have a comment on an answer just add a comment to the answer or update your question instead of creating a new answer.